# rosdep: trouble installing packages in Diamondback (prosilica_camera)

Tags: ros, rosdep, camera-driver, prosilica-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently installed Diamondback using the standard install method for Ubuntu (Lucid)

```
sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-desktop-full
```

I have a couple of Prosilica cameras that I want to test so I'm following the tutorials (http://www.ros.org/wiki/prosilica_camera/Tutorials/DeterminingProsilicaIPAddress). I can't get past the first step of

```
rosdep install prosilica_camera
```

I get a message back saying

```
Warning: could not identify ['prosilica_camera'] as a package
```

I get the same response when I try to use rosdep to install camera_drivers, camera1394, and prosilica_gige_sdk. However, when I try to install rviz, move_base, and other packages that are already installed, I get the response

```
rosdep executing this script:
{{{
set -o errexit
#No Packages to install
}}}
```

Is anyone else having trouble using rosdep to install new packages? Any suggestions on what I should try next? Thanks,

Thomas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9454/rosdep:-trouble-installing-packages-in-diamondback-(prosilica_camera)/) by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4347 on 2011-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm answering my own question. I did not search for the correct terms on this site apparently. I found joq's answer here (http://answers.ros.org/question/169/how-do-i-install-a-missing-ros-package) and that did the trick. I was able to run prosilica nodes after installing with

```
sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-camera-drivers
```

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2011-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1